# SSH through squid proxy running on the same server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, squid

I am currently connecting to my server over ssh. I also have a squid proxy running on the same server, and I would like to be able to connect to ssh through the proxy, presumably with ssh taking place over the server localhost?

Trying to do that currently gives me a 403 response.

What do I need to change in my configuration to make it work?

Also, is this considered good practice, since it will allow to get rid of the ssh dedicated port on the server side?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Reduce amount of open ports?

Comment: Listening ports is not bad. I would rather focus on securing SSH...

Comment: I read it is good practice to not have ssh at the default port. And since I already have the proxy, seems like I can have it at no port and just pass through the proxy.

Comment: *"I read it is good practice to not have ssh at the default port"*  - Changing a port  is usually considered *"security through  obscurity"* and although frequently advocated, it  is not considered good practice. It is not harmful  but also not something that will significantly/effectively  improve your security. Much better are access controls like a firewall allow list.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to call it a security measure of any grade myself. I think the idea is to simply not have ssh at the default port, which would be the first place anyone probes for dictionary attacks. Spare the port the abuse, not throw security measures and cpu time at it. It just seems redundant to have two secure connections to the server, so I would still like to know how to get it working locally on the server if it is not too much trouble. Thanks!

Comment: It may be relevant, but the goal of the proxy is to provide a persistent IP because my IPS uses dynamic so I can't restrict access based on the ip. Seems like passing through the proxy gets two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squid is a HTTP(S) proxy. SSH has its own protocol, which is not compatible with HTTP(S). Therefore you cannot use Squid for this purpose.

You should use a dynamic DNS provider that maps a domain name to your current IP address. For example no-ip.org.

There is ongoing work to implement similar secure shell functionality on top of HTTP/3: https://github.com/francoismichel/ssh3. That one might allow proxy support. But this is still very much work-in-progress so there might be bugs.

Comment: Actually you can, if the squid proxy allows the HTTPS CONNECT() method to the port where SSH is listening you can use a tunnelling helper tool like [`corkscrew`](https://github.com/bryanpkc/corkscrew) to connect via a HTTPS proxy to ssh. Far from recommended though.